# How to configure Android library from gitlab?

Tags: android, gitlab

How to get the android library from Gitlab by adding gitlab url as dependency?

Comment: if you are using AndroidStudio File->import from VersionControl->Git, paste your git url.

Comment: Cant we do it like normal dependency by adding compie 'com.giltab.xxx' ?

Comment: no, we cant If someone make compiled project with creating dependency after then you can.

Comment: If that particular library is on jCenter or Maven repository, you can do that by finding gradle dependency

Comment: show which lib exactly, and I might be able to tell you how to add it

Comment: Actually i created my own library i have it in my gitlab if i want to make available to other projects.Putting those in maven or jcenter is must then ?